# How do you fillet fresh salmon?

Tags: fish

I want to buy a whole piece of fresh salmon, head to tail intact, and fillet it.  Is there a technique that can be shared for a novice?

Answer (score 2):

Filleting a roundfish is really quite easy but is better explained in person or through pictures vs. text.  [Here's a link that will provide step-by-step photos](http://www.clovegarden.com/ingred/seafishcr.html#fillet).